# CPython interactive readline — better backwards deletion of words

Tags: python, configuration, readline

Is it possible to change word boundaries for `readline` in CPython 2.7 or 3.3?

I want `backward-kill-word` (bound to comfortable `C-w`) and `backward-word` have exactly the same word boundaries as `forward-word` and `forward-kill-word`.  Currently `C-w` erases half the line disregarding syntax, dots etc, and stretching out for `M-DEL` for more sensible backwards deletion is too much of a hassle.  I also do not want to use IPython for now.

Simply reconfiguring `C-w` to act like `M-DEL` would be nice (setting it to `backward-kill-word` does not do anything because `M-DEL` function is probably called something else.)

**Update**: it gets stranger!

```
>>> import readline
>>> readline.parse_and_bind('"C-k": backward-kill-word')
(press up, press C-k a lot, witness it working)
>>> readline.parse_and_bind('"\\C-w": backward-kill-word')
(press up, press C-w, and see that its function did not change, it wasn't re-bound!)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question because I have found the answer here:

https://superuser.com/questions/212446/binding-backward-kill-word-to-ctrlw

Short answer is: in addition to adding

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind('"\\C-w": backward-kill-word')
```

to `~/.pythonrc.py`, execute this:

```
stty werase undef
```

sometime before running Python in the same terminal.  This will get control over `C-w` from the terminal.

Not deleting the question in case someone stumbles into the issue in Python interactive context.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @mischa-arefiev's answer, I now have the following in my `PYTHONSTARTUP` file, which works for ipython2 and ipython3:

```
import readline
import subprocess
readline.parse_and_bind('"\\C-w": backward-kill-word')
subprocess.call(['stty', 'werase', 'undef'])
```

I use it on Linux, and I'm not sure if it also works on Mac.